# cannot make window scroll to desired position with window.scrollTo(0,content_scroll_pos);

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simingly simple task at hand, but something is not working correctly :|

There is a button that opens full screen menu, fading out all other content. There is another button that closes menu and fades-in content.

But menu window height can be quite different from content height. So when user clicks open menu, he jumps to the top of the window. But when user closes window he should return to the original window scroll position (exactly where be clicked open menu).

I've this so far *`window.scrollTo(0,content_scroll_pos);` doesn't work! Well it jumps to 0 0. But for given I know content_scroll_pos variable is not 0.

```
//Content window position, before calling menu
var content_scroll_pos;
//Show menu
$("#open_nav").on("click", function(){
    //
    content_scroll_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
    //
    $("#grid_index, #sidebar-big").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        $("nav").fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
});
//Hide menu
$("#close_nav").on("click", function(){
    $("nav").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,content_scroll_pos);
        $("#grid_index, #sidebar-big").fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in browsers console?

Comment: @amrinder007 nope. Just that window.scrollTo(0,content_scroll_pos); goes to 0,0 point. But content_scroll_pos variable is not 0.

Comment: What does `console.log(content_scroll_pos)` give you ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight depending on before click scroll position, atm it gave me 720 for example.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight if it helps, I have code running here: http://mac.idev.ge:800/test/ click menu in the sidebar.

Comment: Well, `content_scroll_pos` at `720` is not an `ordinate` of the `content_scroll_pos`, rather it's the height . `window.scrollTo` works with `co ordinates(x,y)`. By trial and error you have to find the co ordinates where you want the pop up to be positioned and then use that.Any ways , i will look at the code  from the site URL  you posted.

Comment: I saw the the piece of code you wrote in the js file : http://mac.idev.ge:800/test/wp-content/themes/tngabor/js/main.js?ver=1.0 . I still don't understand what exactly you are expecting out of it. I find it working properly. Anything that i am not understanding here ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37504/discussion-between-the-dark-knight-and-sandro-dzneladze)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed problem, by just rearranging events:

```
//Content window position, before calling menu
var content_scroll_pos;
//Show menu
$("#open_nav").on("click", function(){
    //
    content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    //
    $("#grid_index, #sidebar-big").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        $("nav").fadeIn("fast");
    });
    return false;
});
//Hide menu
$("#close_nav").on("click", function(){
    $("nav").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $("#grid_index, #sidebar-big").fadeIn("fast");
        window.scrollTo(0,content_scroll_pos);
    });
    return false;
});
```